# NSXMLParser is not parsing percentage % sign

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser

I have a line in XML that contains % sign. but NSXMLParser changes it too some sort of numbers, as below

```
2013-11-16 01:08:07.102 ECP[46386:a0b] string is Increased Discount to 45% from Sun City Tours
2013-11-16 01:08:07.102 ECP[46386:a0b] Deals CURRENT IS Increased Discount to 45 0.000000rom Sun City Tours
```

My Code in FoundCharacter Method is,

```
  NSLog(@"string is %@", string);

    if([string length]>0)
        [currentStringValue appendFormat:string];

    NSLog(@"Deals CURRENT IS %@", currentStringValue);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `appendString:`, not `appendFormat:`.

`appendFormat:` treats `"% f"` inside the string as a format specification and therefore substitutes it with a floating point number. (And since no corresponding argument
is passed to `appendFormat:`, you have undefined behavior and your program might
crash as well.)